# rollback messages to channel from handlers

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to create a generic Error Handling process for All message Handlers that will be used in my SI flow. This will,
1. Retry on Connection Exception.
2. Stop the SI flow using Circuit Breaker.
3. Rollback the failed message to the channel.

I have achieved the Retry and Circuit Break Functionality. But, I am unable to rollback message to the channel.
I tried using transaction advice. But it does not work.

Here is the code.

```
<bean id="retryAdvice"
    class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
    <property name="retryTemplate">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
            <property name="backOffPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                    <property name="initialInterval" value="2000" />
                    <property name="multiplier" value="2" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="recoveryCallback">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
            <constructor-arg ref="recoveryChannel" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="retryStateGenerator">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.SpelExpressionRetryStateGenerator">
            <constructor-arg value="headers['uniqueId']" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<int:channel id="recoveryChannel" />
<int:transformer id="defaultTransformer" input-channel="recoveryChannel"
    output-channel="loggerChannel" ref="defaultTransformer" method="transform">
</int:transformer>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggerChannel"
    level="INFO" log-full-message="true" auto-startup="true">
</int:logging-channel-adapter>

<bean id="defaultTransformer"
    class="com.bestbuy.ingestion.foundation.core.util.DefaultTransformer" />

<bean id="circuitBreakerAdvice"
    class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice">
    <property name="threshold" value="2" />             <!-- close after 2 failures -->
    <property name="halfOpenAfter" value="60000" />     <!-- half open after 15 seconds -->
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txansactionAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
</tx:advice>
```

What type of Transaction Manager I need to use. 
I may be using different message Handlers, on different data source.

Here is how I add these advises to the Message Handlers.

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {

    logger.error("called for bean id :: "+beanName+" with bean class "+bean.getClass().getName());
    if(bean instanceof AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean){
        logger.error("************ Bean "+beanName+" is instance of AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean **********");
    }
    if(bean instanceof ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean){
        logger.error("Bean is of type ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean");
        return populateRequestHandlerAdviceChain((ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean)bean);
    }
    if(bean instanceof AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean){
        logger.error("Bean is of type AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean");
        return populateRequestHandlerAdviceChain((AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean<?>)bean);
    }
    return bean;
}
private Object populateRequestHandlerAdviceChain(ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean bean){
    ArrayList<Advice> list = new ArrayList<Advice>();
    logger.error("Adding Retry Advice");
    list.add((Advice)factory.getBean("retryAdvice"));
    logger.error("Adding Cricuit Breaker Advice");
    list.add((Advice)factory.getBean("circuitBreakerAdvice"));
    logger.error("Adding Transactional Advice");
    list.add((Advice)factory.getBean("txansactionAdvice"));
    bean.setAdviceChain(list);
    return bean;
}
```

If the bean of type ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean I add these advices. I need transaction management in all these Handlers.

Comment: Show, please how you apply those `Advice`s. The `endpoint` configuration. The `TransactionManager` should be a `PlatformTransactionManager`

Comment: Hi Artem, Updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: since your `txansactionAdvice` is nested to the `retryAdvice` you rollback here the each retry.

From other side it isn't clear why you apply the `circuitBreakerAdvice` for each retry. I'd say this patter would be better to use 'around' `retryAdvice`.

And the `txansactionAdvice` should on top. So, it might look like this:

```
txansactionAdvice
circuitBreakerAdvice
retryAdvice
```

And one more point: your transaction won't be rolled back, bacause your use `recoveryCallback`, which just sends `ErrorMessage` and strangles the Exception.

HTH and you'll change your mind on the matter.

Comment: Thanks Artem This was useful. and now I dont see any message loss .